# How do I pass state as a prop? ( undefined error )

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

app.js:

```
import './App.css';
import HttpService from '../services/http-service'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const http = new HttpService()

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {accounts: ""}
    this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this)
  }
  
  loadData = () => {
    http.getAccounts().then(res =>{
      this.setState({accounts: res})
      console.log(this.accounts)
      return res
    }, err => {console.log(err)})
  }
   
  render() {return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1 className="title">Retail API</h1>
        <DisplayAcc accounts = {this.accounts} />
    </div>
  )}
}

export default App;
```

on DisplayAcc, I have a console.log(this.props.accounts) in the constructor.
Output is undefined. What should I do?
I have tried adding these line:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this)
  }
```

Still undefined. Please point out the error or if you have any suggestions/best practices I would highly appreciate that because I'm very new to this. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, there is no problem on the server side or the http service because when I console.log(res) on after http.getAccount().then the data is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the `accounts` state to be passed down from the App component, to your DisplayAcc commponent:

```js
render() {return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1 className="title">Retail API</h1>
        <DisplayAcc accounts = {this.state.accounts} />
    </div>
  )}
```

Comment: You will also want to change your console log to 

```console.log({this.state.accounts})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the state by you are trying to reach it by `this.accounts`
change it too:

```
this.state.accounts
```

It's more popular to use so called functional components nowadays in the community. By this approach you wouldnot need the constructor, really recommend reading about this since it will simplify your code quite a bit!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this)` is unnecessary because `loadData` is an arrow function.

Secondly, `setState` is an async function so you can't read new state just after calling it. So, the following console log will be `undefined`

```
this.setState({accounts: res})
console.log(this.accounts) // also this must be this.state.accounts!
```

Moreover, you are trying to get state value in a wrong way, it must be:

```
<DisplayAcc accounts={this.state.accounts} />
```

If you want to read accounts prop in `DisplayAcc` component, you should add your console log to whether in `render` or `componentDidUpate` methods because `constructor` is only called on first render and your `accounts` props is empty at that time. But the ones I mentioned are called every time the props are changed.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't see where `loadData` is called, which makes me suspicious about the value of `accounts`.
2. Consistency is key: if `accounts` is part of the component's state, then you should access it via `this.state.accounts`, rather than `this.accounts`.
3. Please notice that you `console.log` meaningfully. Hence, if you want to check `this.account`, there's no point printing `res`, as you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Yeah my bad, I forgot to write loadData() in the question but I have it under componentDidMount(). It works now....and as far as the console.log(res), you see it is the variable assigned to the parameter of the .then function. Thanks anyways.